# jQuery | Detach / Append troubleshoot - multiple button click

Tags: jquery, append, detach

i've got following problem with this script: [goo.gl/KSCk5E](http://goo.gl/KSCk5E)

this script works pretty like I want it. As long as I click only one time at the buttons. But after clicking a button multiple times, it stops working. Unfortunately I am not able to solve it. I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps instead of detaching the `<div>`s on the click event, you could simple `hide()` or `toggle()` them? I feel that this would solve your issue.

Comment: Here is a JS fiddle of what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/cxMBR/9/

Comment: hey thanks for your comment. But I must use detach removing elements to add them later.

Any other ideas?

Comment: I've played with your fiddle, and can't really figure out what you want to do. What exactly do you want to hhappen when you click on each of the button?

Comment: there will be two pretty complex forms which are pretty similar except of two elements. I really don't want to rewrite all my stuff twice. so my plan was to exclude / detach either form AAA by clicking button BBB and vice versa to avoid "needless" script.

maybe it's totally idiotic. i am pretty new to programming but it works nearly perfect except of that doubleclick issue.

Comment: in other words: if Button AAA is clicked Form BBB is "not existent" (vice versa)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/cxMBR/10/

thats the solution